# How to set woocommerce product wise Mailchimp list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, mailchimp, product

How to set woocommerce product wise Mailchimp list? anyone know solutions for this them please update me.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure your WooCommerce is integrated with your Mailchimp using WooChimp plugin. Now, as per my understanding you want to set WooCommerce product wise Mailchimp list.

Under Settings, you can create any number of sets and add the products in the condition for which you want it to be activated.

You can create any number of combinations and sets for your WP site.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

But mail chimp directly not provide product wise mailchimp list integration functionality.

Comment: No MailChimp doesn't. But you can use the WooChimp plugin to make these settings.

Comment: Can you please send me that plugin URL.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install "WooCommerce MailChimp" Plugin.
2. Integrate it using Mail chimp API key. I hope u know how to do.
3. Create lists in mail chimp account.
4. Subscribe mails into lists according to the products with plugin settings or programmatically using mailchimp subscription API. For more info check: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/